# I received a payment error during my ESTA application; what can I do?

Tags: visas

I received a payment error during my ESTA application and still need to pay. The current application status for the last few hours shows:

> THE PAYMENT STATUS COULD NOT BE DETERMINED AT THIS TIME. 
>   PLEASE CHECK BACK LATER FOR THE PAYMENT STATUS.

Your application is not complete and will not be processed by CBP until the processing fee has been paid.

You must complete payment within 7 days.

Comment: https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/ - check existing application says "Update unpaid or approved application.". Have you tried that?